# How powerful is Twilight Sparkle?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

Over the course of season one it seemed as though Twilights repertoire of magic was rather narrow, but as season two has progressed she has gained more and more magical power. She can perform time and space travel, force fields and the like.

Is there any indication of a grade or power level she has achieved? Perhaps in a letter from Princess Celestia? Is her level of magical aptitude normal for a unicorn?

Comment: Here's a really excellent post from Reddit outlining all of the abilities Twilight has demonstrated as of Season 6: https://reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/56b180/respect_twilight_sparkle_mlpfim/ (Updated)

Comment: @Ajedi32 Bountied!

Comment: Do you think I should post that as an answer? (With additional explanation and the relevant parts from the Reddit post quoted, of course.) The only reason I haven't yet was that your question currently seems to be asking for some kind of official ranking or grade, rather than just a raw analysis of Twilight's demonstrated abilities.

Comment: @Ajedi32 only because I didn't know/think such an analysis would be a succinct 'good subjective' answer. It sounds worth posting though.

Comment: Are you interested in temporary abilities as well? There was an episode where Twilight was arguably one of the most powerful entities in the universe. She reverts back at the conclusion.

Comment: Strike her down and she will become more powerful than you can possibly imagine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any indication of a grade or power level she has achieved? Perhaps in a letter from Princess Celestia?

The only thing offhand I can think of that would fit this description is her status as Princess Celestia's apprentice/most loyal student (see [the character sidebar and summary on Twilight Sparkle's fandom page](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/Twilight_Sparkle)).

> Twilight Sparkle is a unicorn pony who is **a special and loyal apprentice of Princess Celestia** [...]

---

> Is her level of magical aptitude normal for a unicorn?

She's actually quite capable with magic in contrast to most unicorn ponies, who usually only get a basic couple of powers (mainly telekinesis AFAICT) and one or more special spells related to their cutie mark (for example, Rarity's gem finding spell).

She has shown that there are limits to the power she can exert (only barely being able to levitate the Ursa Minor back to its cave in Boast Busters being a prime example), and she's demonstrated that she can quickly learn even complex spells (glancing at the time travel spell scroll in It's About Time, then nearly immediately casting it).

As far as present limits, it seems to vary based on the spell in question. A few examples:

- Twilight's teleport spell is dependent upon distance traveled and what she's teleporting with her. In Dragon Quest, she exerts considerable effort to teleport her, Spike, Rainbow Dash, and Rarity to safety (this is as far as Twilight has attempted to stretch her teleport spell), whereas she can ordinarily use her teleport spell with next to no visible effort for short-range teleportation. (An aside, if she's not careful with how she uses it, the teleport spell will drag others nearby with her, with somewhat unpleasant results)
- She apparently has the ability to make cutie marks appear on ponies who don't have them, with effort expended roughly corresponding to speed at which they appear. (this spell is of questionable utility, but *shrug*)
- The effort required to use telekinesis seems to vary based on the weight of the objects being manipulated. She is seen in Applebuck season harvesting an entire orchard with little effort, while the Ursa Minor was difficult to move. (entirely speculation would be that it takes more effort to lift large objects, and more coordination to manipulate things in quantity)
- She also had the ability to manufacture facial hair (Spell 25), and if memory serves she progressed fairly quickly with the use of that spell throughout Boast Busters.
- She gained the ability to fire what are essentially lasers from her horn as of A Canterlot Wedding - Part 2, ostensibly through off-screen/inter-episode studies.

As a more general statement, I would speculate that Twilight is running into spell limits before she's running out of energy to execute them (given that she easily cast the aforementioned time-travel spell, and the only thing stopping her from reusing it is the spell's once-per-caster limit). Just conjecture though, since the science of unicorn magic isn't well defined to us viewers.

> Twilight is exceptional in regard to magic, having dedicated herself to studying the art. Spike mentions in Boast Busters that Twilight's magical ability is exemplary, and Princess Celestia comments about Twilight's enormous raw magical power in The Cutie Mark Chronicles. Unicorn magic requires concentration and effort, as Twilight explains to Spike at the beginning of Feeling Pinkie Keen and to the Cutie Mark Crusaders in Call of the Cutie, [...]
>
> Twilight is shown developing her skills in a flashback in The Cutie Mark Chronicles, where she has some difficulty using magic to turn a page in her book; the scene shows her progressing in her studies, a theme which continues throughout the series.
>
> Twilight possesses the ability to teleport, which was also common among previous-generation My Little Pony unicorn characters. She first teleports on the show in Friendship is Magic, part 2 when she charges Night Mare Moon and disappears only to reappear behind her and next to the Elements of Harmony. She teleports short distances in Applebuck Season to get ahead of Applejack trying to confront her about her over-exertion, and she unintentionally teleports with Spike from the thoroughfare into her library in The Ticket Master, which leaves Spike slightly singed. She teleports multiple times in Lesson Zero, seemingly without effort. As seen in Secret of My Excess, she is able to teleport other beings as well, teleporting Spike several times to clean a lipstick mark off his cheek.

[quotes sourced from the [My Little Pony wiki](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/My_Little_Pony_Friendship_is_Magic_Wiki)]

Comment: The thing is she's performed more powerful magic since lifting the ursa minor, and that was season one. Do you see my point about a progression?

Comment: @Pureferret: I'd be happy to expand a bit on that if you'd like :)

Comment: Yes please! That would be ace.

Comment: @Pureferret: Done. I'd be making stuff up if i wrote any more on the subject I think :P

Comment: Looks perfect to me now.

Comment: On second thought, I could probably ramble on for a few more paragraphs. But this is a good enough answer, so I'll leave it.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: If you're looking for the most raw magical power Twilight has ever wielded, well [this happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsbbWOzNY7c) which results in [this happening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoC5WTnUUCM) in the season 4 *Twilight's Kingdom Pt. 2*. This is only temporary as the other alicorn magic is returned on Tirek's defeat... but she shows incredible power and probably could have done some unbelievable feats given more time to adjust to her new power levels. Of course, she later uses friendship magic on Tirek which seems much more effective.

Answer (score 10):

As the seasons progress, Twilight's power grows.

Notice the spell of teleportation:

- In S1E2, while confronting Nightmare Moon, the single teleportation across the room takes a lot of effort and leaves her visibly dizzy.
- Sometime later in the same season, during S1E4; "Applebuck Season" she teleports around casually, chasing Applejack around. Apparently, after confronting Nightmare Moon she got to training that spell thoroughly. Nevertheless, during several dangerous situations throughout this and next season, she at most teleports herself.
- Then, in S2E21 - "Dragon Quest" she casts a mass teleport, taking herself, Spike, Rainbow Dash and Rarity by a distance that apparently took days to cross on hoof.

Her power was way beyond that of any normal unicorn during the whole timeline of the story, even fairly early on, as is clearly outlined in Boast Busters (S1E6) when she hypothesizing that since most unicorns have assorted talents aided by their magic, and Twilight's special talent *is* magic, her skill exceeds that of everypony else. Nevertheless, this isn't purely inborn. S1E16 - Sonic Rainboom - reminisces at her as a small filly struggling to flip a page in a book using her magic. Then, the rainboom wakes her potential up, but it still takes years of careful study that let her master that magic - and her studies in Ponyville are just another phase on her way to ascension.

Events of S4 finale shed some light on her power levels as alicorn: they are similar to power of other princesses, and considering the even match against Tirek while wielding power of all four - alicorn power is about one fourth the power of the whole pony population of Equestria.

Note that independently from her "normal" unicorn/alicorn magic, while in cooperation with the rest of mane 6, Twilight wields a separate type of magic - the magic of friendship - and it's a game-breaker power, implied to be limitless: *"There is magic without the end".*

Answer (score 5):

Twilight [has always possessed a much higher than usual level of raw magical potential](https://youtu.be/oelXoNPKjKE?t=56s) (S1E25 *The Cutie Mark Chronicles*), with Celestia [stating](https://youtu.be/oelXoNPKjKE?t=1m6s) that:

> You have a very special gift. I don't think I've ever come across a unicorn with your raw abilities.

Keep in mind that Celestia was well over 1000 years old when she said this, and knew legendary unicorns like [Starswirl the Bearded](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Swirl_the_Bearded) personally, so coming from her this statement means a lot.

Twilight and Spike later [elaborate on this](https://youtu.be/Gn1Ecvdy3qY?t=40s) in *Boast Busters* (S1E6), stating that most unicorns only possess a small amount of magic related to their unique talents:

> **Spike:** Twenty-five, Twilight. Twenty-five different kinds of tricks and counting. I thought unicorns were only supposed to have a little magic that matches their special talents!
>
> **Twilight Sparkle:** True, for ponies whose talents are for things like cooking or singing or math. But what if a unicorn's special talent *is* magic?

Your perception that Twilight's magical powers have grown over time however is also correct. Since Twilight first took on her role as Celestia's student, her skill at utilizing various spells to perform feats of magical strength has improved considerably.

A couple examples:

Back when Twilight was still quite young, [she struggled to perform even a simple levitation spell](https://youtu.be/oelXoNPKjKE?t=17s) (S1E25 *The Cutie Mark Chronicles*). Later, she is able to, with considerable effort, use that same spell to [levitate a large magical creature (an Ursa Minor) and the town's water tower a considerable distance](https://youtu.be/tFDYxrodzSk?t=35s) (S1E6 *Boast Busters*).

In Season 1 Episode 2 (*Friendship is Magic*), Twilight [needs to power up and concentrate](https://youtu.be/ZJqiUobl4uY?t=5m10s) in order to teleport herself a short distance in front of her. Later she [accidentally teleports herself and Spike](https://youtu.be/C6ntk04n1qI?t=2m20s) a longer distance, with unfortunate side effects for Spike (S1E3 *The Ticket Master*). The very next episode we see Twilight [casually teleporting herself around during a conversation with one of her friends](https://youtu.be/jhk_Cyq7cWE?t=35s) (S1E4 *Applebuck Season*), and eventually we even [see her cast a mass teleport](https://youtu.be/4TXtXc5ZpzM?t=3m31s) (S2E21 *Dragon Quest*), taking herself, three other characters, and an egg a very significant distance (all the way out of a forest). She continues to cast teleport spells frequently throughout the series, [sometimes casually](https://youtu.be/jzH1FVpn2Ts?t=1m30s) (S4E21 *Testing Testing 1, 2, 3*), [sometimes seemingly without thinking](https://youtu.be/HrCu-GLXqBA?t=1m29s) (S4E1 *Princess Twilight Sparkle*), and [sometimes to get herself out of sticky situations](https://youtu.be/9xFr2B-NMqI?t=3m24s) (S5E21 *Scare Master*), demonstrating that she's mastered this ability.

In these situations it appears that it's not so much Twilight's level of magical power increasing as it is her skill with each individual spell.

As of Season 6 Twilight has demonstrated skill with a wide variety of spells, ranging from [force fields](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBLUqpNVMio) to [gravity manipulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQBOIAI9Fzs) to [brainwashing](https://youtu.be/G_N02MgxtAs?t=4m42s). [/u/selfproclaimed](https://www.reddit.com/user/selfproclaimed) on Reddit has compiled [an extensive list of these abilites](https://www.reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/56b180/respect_twilight_sparkle_mlpfim/). Here is the section from that list related to magic:

> As a member of the unicorn race, Twilight can manifest her inherit magic into a multitude of spells through her horn. Through her years of study and hard work, Twilight’s spellcasting abilities far exceed those of any naturally born Unicorn for at least a thousand years. She is capable of [copying any spell she's seen](https://gfycat.com/cluelessforsakenimpala), sometimes even improving it, even if she has only [seen it once before and a type of magic she is unfamiliar with.](https://gfycat.com/untidyoccasionallarva)
>
> **Concussive blasts**
>
> - [Twilight can utilize a laser-like stream of magical energy that is at least wall-busting in terms of destructive capability. This is usually what Twilight opens with in a fight.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZvVP.jpg). <sup>IDW</sup>
> - [Vaporizes large crystals and a rock with it.](https://gfycat.com/windycomplicateditalianbrownbear) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Intercepts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSVPP.jpg) and matches [a blast from Chrysalis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSXH1.jpg). <sup>IDW</sup>
> - [This attack can be used to hit multiple targets at once. Twilight can vary the power of it to have it merely stun or hurt a target.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9na3.jpg) That being said, Twilight has never demonstrated this to have the same destructive capability while targeting multiples, so it is very possible that by doing so she sacrifices power. <sup>IDW</sup>
> - [There is a variation that allows Twilight to encase a target in crystal.](https://gfycat.com/totalfrenchgalapagosalbatross) <sup>FIM</sup>
>
> **Force Field**
>
> - [Strong enough to block a concussive beam fired by Starlight Glimmer](https://gfycat.com/fairhauntingblackfly) <sup>FIM</sup>
>
>   - For comparison, Starlight's concussive beams [are powerful enough to blast apart a huge chunk of a stone bridge](https://gfycat.com/affectionatescornfulinganue) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Capable of creating force fields up to sizes large enough to surround a building.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsfQP.png). <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Has a similar "Bubble of Silence" Spell that contains all sound within the force field.](https://gfycat.com/vigorousplayfulgoldenretriever) <sup>FIM</sup>
>
> **Teleportation**
>
> - [Can teleport self over long distances rapidly](https://gfycat.com/forthrightfoolishdungbeetle). <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Able to teleport others objects or people](https://gfycat.com/sphericallargebustard) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Teleported four targets, including herself, out of a forest while sprinting.](https://gfycat.com/everlastingbabyishemperorshrimp). <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Teleported six targets, including herself, from a prone position](https://gfycat.com/carelessimmenseamericantoad) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Can Summon a Parasprite, a small matter-eating being capable of multiplying infinitely](https://gfycat.com/allscholarlyarcticwolf) <sup>FIM</sup>
>
> **Telekinesis**
>
> - [Able to carry a large building+ sized monster with a filled water tower a fair distance. (from the center of town to a cave in a nearby forest)](https://gfycat.com/conventionalacceptablehare) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [After a dam broke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VEe6.jpg), Twilight levitated [every last piece of the structure and moved it against the water pressure and repaired the dam in seconds.](https://gfycat.com/brownconcreteindianglassfish) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Capable of lifting liquid matter, while manipulating herself to stand on water.](https://gfycat.com/grimyamazingenglishpointer) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Able to utilize it as a stasis spell to stop multiple targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUkkX.gif) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - However, the more targets she's stopping, the more effort she needs to exert as seen [when she was struggling to hold two families in place.](https://gfycat.com/thisfluffydragon) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Targeted and plucked a large field of apples from their trees without disturbing the trees themselves.](https://gfycat.com/esteemedunrulyamericanalligator) <sup>FIM</sup>
>
> **Transmutation**
>
> - [Capable of transforming small objects or creatures into an orange](https://gfycat.com/yearlybraveacornwoodpecker) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Transformed an apple into a nest of bird eggs (one of them **hatching instantly**), an quil in ink into a top hat, a book into a watermelon, and a photograph into a banana.](https://gfycat.com/insignificantimmaculatearctichare) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - [Has a similar spell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGMoT.jpg) that can turn creatures [into apples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbChk.jpg). <sup>IDW</sup>
> - [Is stated to have once transformed half a classroom into plants.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA2kY.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>
>
> **Miscellaneous Spells**
>
> - [Can manifest herself within a book for several minutes as an illustration. This illustration can communicate with the outside world. The spell was originally used to speed up the process of information gathering from a book.](https://gfycat.com/legitimategivingcats) To quote Twilight "I've been studying a new studying technique...You'd be amazed what you can pick up when you're actually *in* a book." <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Sentience Inducement]** [Come to Life Spell can automate simple machines to move on their own.](https://gfycat.com/possiblescalyduck) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Phasing]** [Can utilize magic to phase through solid material.](https://gfycat.com/rarevaluablebuffalo) <sup>FIM</sup>
>
>   - [More use of phasing magic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtRUq.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>
> - **[Gravity Manipulation]** [Capable of using a spell that changes her own gravity polarity.](https://gfycat.com/glossymagnificentanhinga) <sup>FIM</sup>
>
>   - [This is stated to be capable of being town-wide in its
>     range.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJGOB.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>
> - **[Brainwashing]** [Want It Need It Spell causes anyone, excluding the caster, to become obsessed with a target object upon eye contact](https://gfycat.com/candiddefensiveflea) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Brainwashing]** [Can reprogram a creature’s dietary nature.](https://gfycat.com/thoroughgenuineblackbear) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Mind Delving]** [Magical Mindscape Manifestation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOQee.jpg) spell allows [Twilight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfBMj.jpg) to enter the [mind of a subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX5B7.jpg). The resulting mindscape [reflects a person’s life and personality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGVoH.jpg) and even contains beings that reflect a person’s [multiple moods and “sides” of themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YldFN.jpg). <sup>IDW</sup>
> - **[Time Travel]** [Can go back in time, but can only stay in the past for about a minute before she is brought back to the present.](https://gfycat.com/acclaimedfarflungaustraliankestrel) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Pyrokenesis]** [Lights an Olympic-like cauldron](https://gfycat.com/jubilantelegantalbatross). <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Voice Manipulation]** [Increased the volume of her own voice to be heard by opposite ends of a valley.](https://gfycat.com/distinctconcreteaxisdeer) <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Recording]** [Capable of recording audio and video which can then be displayed like a projector](https://gfycat.com/competentdishonestcaiman). <sup>FIM</sup>
> - **[Camouflage]** ["Don't-Notice-Me-Field" changes the user's appearance to blend in with the environment. The closer you get to a viewer, however, the less effective it is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRjSN.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>
> - **[Traumalocation]** ["Traumalocation" spell, when cast on someone who has recently been the victim of some form of attack, can be used to locate and view the person or persons who committed the act.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvY7x.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>
> - **[Mind Melding]** [Spell that combines the consciousness of another character into the caster's own body.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeF5s.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>
> - **[Speed Enhancement]** [Twilight can magically accelerate her own speed that allows her to fly at supersonic speeds. The shock wave produced has a strong enough push to knock someone off their feet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUTf.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>
> - **[Magic Sealing]** [Twilight can take a target's ability to cast magic completely away, though the effect is temporary.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADulk.jpg) <sup>IDW</sup>

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects the media you included in your post since they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you edit your post and reupload the media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE Imgur. See [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13948/7957) for more info.